# How to run a cuPy python program on NVIDIA NGC?

Tags: python, docker, nvidia, cupy, nvidia-docker

I have a python program that utilizes NVIDIA GPU using **cuPy** package. The program runs fine with my local laptop's GPU and on a ubuntu GPU cluster. Now for scalability reasons, I want to make my program able to run on **[NVIDIA GPU Cloud (NGC)](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/gpu-cloud/)**.

To run the program on NGC, what I understood so far is, I need to do the following:

- Containerized my program
- install docker
- run the program using docker

with my very limited experience with Docker, I am not able to understand the following:

- how do I install cuPy docker image? Should I use install [Chainer image](https://catalog.ngc.nvidia.com/orgs/partners/containers/chainer) instead?
- my program contains some `with cupy.cuda.Device(device=device_id)` statements to select different GPUs, can I keep the statements? or do I need to remove these statements?

I want to start with trying to run the following simple program on NGC, but not sure the exact steps I need to follow.

**MWE:**

```
import cupy as cp

# Create a random matrix on the GPU
a_gpu = cp.random.rand(1000, 1000)

# Perform a matrix multiplication on the GPU
result_gpu = cp.dot(a_gpu, a_gpu)

# Transfer the result back to the CPU
result_cpu = cp.asnumpy(result_gpu)

# Print the result
print(result_cpu)
```